# Tcp connection exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

my server has a list of 4 TCP connected clients . if list full , next client must reject

//Server side

```
unit ServerUnit;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, IdThreadMgr, IdThreadMgrDefault, IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze,
IdUDPBase, IdUDPServer, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPServer,
StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,IdSocketHandle, ComCtrls, IdUDPClient, Grids,
IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
 Panel1: TPanel;
 Label3: TLabel;
 Edit3: TEdit;
 Button1: TButton;
 IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
 IdUDPServer1: TIdUDPServer;
 IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
 IdThreadMgrDefault1: TIdThreadMgrDefault;
 StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
 GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
 IncomingText: TMemo;
 GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
 Clients_StringGrid: TStringGrid;
 IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 procedure IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
 procedure ADDTCPConn(AThread: TIdPeerThread;i:Integer);
 procedure DeleteRow1(VGrid: TStringGrid; VRow: integer);
 procedure InsertRow1(VGrid: TStringGrid; Str1:String; Str2:String; Str3:String);
 Procedure Add_To_StringGrid(Grid:TStringGrid; Str1:String; Str2:String; Str3:String; i:Integer);
 procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
 procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;
RCount:Integer;
flag:Boolean;
IPList : TStringList;
IPList2 : TStringList;
fl: Boolean;

implementation

uses CommonUnit;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if not IdUDPServer1.Active then
 begin
  IdUDPServer1.DefaultPort:=1717;
  IdUDPServer1.BroadcastEnabled:=True;
  IdUDPServer1.Active:=True;
 end;
 if not IdTCPServer1.Active then
 begin
  IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort:=1717;
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=True;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
 ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
 s : String;
 ip : String;
 dss : TStringStream;
begin
 try
  dss := TStringStream.Create('');
  dss.CopyFrom(AData, AData.Size);
  s := dss.DataString;
  ip:=GetIPAddress();
  IncomingText.Lines.Add('Client Say('+ABinding.PeerIP+'):'+s);
  IncomingText.Lines.Add('------------');
  ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, ip[1], Length(ip));
  dss.Free();
 except
 on E : Exception do
  WriteLogFile(E.message);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ADDTCPConn(AThread: TIdPeerThread;i:Integer);
var
NewClientIP : String;
begin
  NewClientIP := AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
 //NewClientHostName := IPAddrToName(NewClientIP);
 //Add_To_StringGrid(Clients_StringGrid,NewClientIP,'ggg','eee',i);
 InsertRow1(Clients_StringGrid,NewClientIP,'ggg','eee');
 IncomingText.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Time)+' Connection from "' + 'ggg' + '" on ' + NewClientIP);
 IncomingText.Lines.Add('------------');
 StatusBar1.Panels.Items[0].Text := ' Status : TCP Connected';
 flag:=true;
end;

Procedure TForm1.Add_To_StringGrid(Grid:TStringGrid; Str1:String; Str2:String; Str3:String;
 i:Integer);     
Begin
 if i=-1 then
 begin
  if RCount <> 0 then
   Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount + 1;
  RCount:=RCount+1;
  Grid.Cells[0,RCount] := Str1;
  Grid.Cells[1,RCount] := Str2;
  Grid.Cells[2,RCount] := Str3;
 end
 else
 begin
  Grid.Cells[0,i] := Str1;
  Grid.Cells[1,i] := Str2;
  Grid.Cells[2,i] := Str3;
 end;
End;

procedure TForm1.InsertRow1(VGrid: TStringGrid; Str1:String; Str2:String; Str3:String);
begin
 if RCount<>0 then
  VGrid.RowCount:= VGrid.RowCount + 1;
 VGrid.Cells[0, VGrid.RowCount - 1]:= Str1;
 VGrid.Cells[1, VGrid.RowCount - 1]:= Str2;
 VGrid.Cells[2, VGrid.RowCount - 1]:= Str3;
 RCount:=RCount+1;
end;


procedure TForm1.DeleteRow1(VGrid: TStringGrid; VRow: integer);
var
I, J: Integer;
begin
if VGrid.RowCount = 2 then
begin
 VGrid.Rows[1].CommaText:= '"","","","",""';
end
else
begin
 for I:= VRow to VGrid.RowCount - 2 do
  for J:=0 to VGrid.ColCount - 1 do
   VGrid.Cells[J,I]:= VGrid.Cells[J, I + 1];
  VGrid.RowCount:= VGrid.RowCount - 1;
end;
RCount:=RCount-1;
if RCount=0 then
 VGrid.RowCount:= 2;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 RCount:=0;
 Clients_StringGrid.Cells[0, 0]:= 'Client IP';
 Clients_StringGrid.Cells[1, 0]:= 'Host Name';
 Clients_StringGrid.Cells[2, 0]:= 'Versa';
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 if flag then
  AThread.Connection.WriteLn('Reply')
 else
  AThread.Connection.WriteLn('Reject');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
j:Integer;
fl:Boolean;
IP:String;
IPList2 : TStringList;
Count:Integer;
i:Integer;
begin
 try
  Count:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
  IP:= AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  if (Clients_StringGrid.Cols[0].IndexOf(IP) = -1) then
  begin
   if RCount < Count then
   begin
    if (Clients_StringGrid.Cols[0].IndexOf(IP) = -1) then
     ADDTCPConn(AThread,-1)
    else
    begin
     StatusBar1.Panels.Items[0].Text := ' Status : TCP Already Connected';
     flag:=True;
    end;
   end
   else
   begin
   IPList:=TStringList.Create;
   IPList2:=TStringList.Create;
   fl:=False;
   IPList.Clear;
   IPList2.Clear;
   For i:=1 To Count Do
   begin
    IdTCPClient1.Host := Clients_StringGrid.Cells[0,i];
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 1112;
    if IdTCPClient1.connected then
     IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    try
     IdTCPClient1.Connect();
     IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
     IPList.Add(Clients_StringGrid.Cells[0,i]);
    except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
     IPList2.Add(Clients_StringGrid.Cells[0,i]);
     fl:=True;
    end;
   end;
 end;
 IncomingText.Lines.Add('Num Act ip:'+IntToStr(IPList.Count));
 For j:=1 To IPList2.Count Do
 begin
  IncomingText.Lines.Add('row Del'+IntToStr(Clients_StringGrid.Cols[0].IndexOf(IPList2[j-1])));
  DeleteRow1(Clients_StringGrid,Clients_StringGrid.Cols[0].IndexOf(IPList2[j-1]));
 end;
 if fl then
 begin
  ADDTCPConn(AThread,-1);
  flag:=True;
 end
 else
  flag:=false;
 IPList.Free;
 IPList2.Free;
end;
end
else
begin
 StatusBar1.Panels.Items[0].Text := ' Status : TCP Already Connected';
 flag:=True;
end;
except
on E : Exception do
 WriteLogFile(E.message);
end;
end;

end.
```

//Client Side

```
unit ClientUnit;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze,
 IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase,
 IdUDPClient, ComCtrls, IdUDPServer,IdSocketHandle,IdStack, IdTCPServer,
 IdThreadMgr, IdThreadMgrDefault;

 type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  Panel1: TPanel;
  Label3: TLabel;
  Edit3: TEdit;
  Button1: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
  Button3: TButton;
  StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
  GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
  IncomingText: TMemo;
  IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
  IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
  IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
  IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
  IdThreadMgrDefault1: TIdThreadMgrDefault;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
 private
  { Private declarations }
 public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
 Form2: TForm2;
 ServerIP:String;

implementation

uses CommonUnit;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if not IdUDPClient1.Active then
 begin
  IdUDPClient1.Port:=1717;
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled:=True;
  IdUDPClient1.Active:=True;
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=False;
 end;
 Button1.Enabled:=False;
 Button2.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 StrIn : String;
 StrOut : String;
begin
try
 StrOut:='Request';
 IdUDPClient1.Broadcast(StrOut, 1717);
 StrIn := IdUDPClient1.ReceiveString(100);
 if not (StrIn='') then
 begin
  Button3.Enabled:=True;
  Button2.Enabled:=False;
  IncomingText.Lines.Add('UDP Reply');
  StatusBar1.Panels.Items[0].Text := 'Status : UDP Connected';
  ServerIP := StrIn;
 end
 else
  WriteLogFile('UDP Connection Failed');
except
on E : Exception do
 WriteLogFile(E.Message);
end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 StrIn : String;
begin
 try
  if ServerIP<>'' then
  begin
   IdTCPClient1.Host := ServerIP ;
   IdTCPClient1.Port := 1717 ;
   IdTCPClient1.Connect;
   StrIn:= IdTCPClient1.ReadLn();
   //IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
   if StrIn<>'' then
   begin
    IncomingText.Lines.Add(StrIn);
    if StrIn<>'Reply' then
     StatusBar1.Panels.Items[0].Text :='Connected To TCPServer';
    else
    begin
     Button3.Enabled:=False;
     Button1.Enabled:=True;
    end;
   end
   else
    WriteLogFile('TCP Connection Failed');
  end;
  except
  on E : Exception do
   WriteLogFile(E.message);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 //check point
end;

end.
```

//when in event onconnect on server want to check clients in list , line IdTCPClient1.Connect() return error
1)Socket Error # 10022 Invalid argument.
2)Connection Closed Gracefully.

and never run onexcute on client side
why this hapened

Comment: As I tried to explain to you earlier, you really need to stop trying to use UDP to validate your TCP connections. Your `TIdTCPServer` code should be validating the TCP connections directly, using heartbeats/keepalives. I'm on the Indy dev team. I didn't advise you to do that just for the hell of it. It is the right thing to do.

Comment: As for your actual errors, `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdUDPServer` are multi-threaded components, but your event handlers are not even close to using thread-safe code, so that can cause all kinds of side effects. For example, if 2 clients connect to the `TIdTCPServer` at the same time, they will share the same `TIdTCPClient` object and interfer with each other.

Comment: From what I can understand, when server's list is full the server is trying to `Connect` from server-side to each client to port 1112. Do you really mean this?

Comment: yes to ensure thay are still connected

Comment: Do not use UDP for that. Do not have the server use a separate TCP client for that. The server needs to validate its existing TCP connections periodically to make sure they are still responsive, disconnecting them if they are not. What is unclear about that? You are making things WAY TOO COMPLICATED for what you keep asking for.